# Sort boxplot and colour by pairs

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have some data for conditions that go together by pairs, structured like this:

```
mydata = {
    "WT_before": [11,12,13],
    "WT_after": [16,17,18],
    "MRE11_before": [21,22,23,24,25],
    "MRE11_after": [26,27,28,29,30],
    "NBS1_before": [31,32,33,34],
    "NBS1_after": [36,37,38,39]
}
```

(my real data has more conditions and more values per condition, this is just an example)

I looked into colouring the boxplots by pairs to help reading the figure, but it seemed quite convoluted to do in **matplotlib**.

For the moment I'm doing it this way:

```
bxplt_labels, bxplt_data = mydata.keys(), mydata.values()
bxplt_colors = ["pink", "pink", "lightgreen", "lightgreen", "lightblue", "lightblue"]

fig2, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=500)
bplot = plt.boxplot(bxplt_data, vert=False, showfliers=False, notch=False, patch_artist=True,)
for patch, color in zip(bplot['boxes'], bxplt_colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)
plt.yticks(range(1, len(bxplt_labels) + 1), bxplt_labels)
fig2.show()
```

which produces the figure:
[image: basic plot produced with this code]

I would like:

1. to sort the condition names, so that I can order them to my choosing, and
2. to get a more elegant way of choosing the colours used, in particular because I will need to reuse this data for more figures afterwards (like scatterplot before/after for each condition)

If it is needed, I can rearrange the data structure, but each condition doesn't have the same number of values, so a dictionary seemed like the best option for me. Alternatevely, I can use **seaborn**, which I saw has quite a few possibilities, but I'm not familiar with it, so I would need more time to understand it.

Could you help me to figure out?

Comment: The question seems to be broad. How are you expecting the plot to be? What is the condition you are talking about? Edit the post to a structured requirement.

Comment: @Roxy I am expecting the plot to be sorted on the Y axis by a given order (for example: WT, MRE11, NBS1, like in the declaration of the data). The "condition" is the parameters of the experiments from which the data was collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn works easiest with a dataframe in "long form". In this case, there would be rows with the condition repeated for every value with that condition.

Seaborn's boxplot accepts an `order=` keyword, where you can change the order of the x-values.  E.g. `order=sorted(mydata.keys())` to sort the values alphabetically. Or `list(mydata.keys())[::-1]` to use the original order, but reversed. The default order would be how the values appear in the dataframe.

For a horizontal boxplot, you can use `x='value', y='condition'`. The order will apply to either x or y, depending on which column contains strings.

For coloring, you can use the `palette=` keyword. This can either be a string indicating one of matplotlib's or seaborn's colormaps. Or it can be a list of colors.  [Many more options are possible.](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

mydata = {
     "WT_before": [11, 12, 13],
     "WT_after": [16, 17, 18],
     "MRE11_before": [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
     "MRE11_after": [26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
     "NBS1_before": [31, 32, 33, 34],
     "NBS1_after": [36, 37, 38, 39]
}
df = pd.DataFrame([[k, val] for k, vals in mydata.items() for val in vals],
                  columns=['condition', 'value'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='condition', y='value',
            order=['WT_before', 'WT_after', 'MRE11_before', 'MRE11_after', 'NBS1_before', 'NBS1_after'],
            palette='turbo', ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot from long form data]

Here is an example with horizontal boxes:

```py
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='value', y='condition', palette='Paired')
sns.despine()
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot horizontally]

The dataframe would look like:

|  | condition | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | WT_before | 11 |
| 1 | WT_before | 12 |
| 2 | WT_before | 13 |
| 3 | WT_after | 16 |
| 4 | WT_after | 17 |
| 5 | WT_after | 18 |
| 6 | MRE11_before | 21 |
| 7 | MRE11_before | 22 |
| 8 | MRE11_before | 23 |
| 9 | MRE11_before | 24 |
| 10 | MRE11_before | 25 |
| 11 | MRE11_after | 26 |
| 12 | MRE11_after | 27 |
| 13 | MRE11_after | 28 |
| 14 | MRE11_after | 29 |
| 15 | MRE11_after | 30 |
| 16 | NBS1_before | 31 |
| 17 | NBS1_before | 32 |
| 18 | NBS1_before | 33 |
| 19 | NBS1_before | 34 |
| 20 | NBS1_after | 36 |
| 21 | NBS1_after | 37 |
| 22 | NBS1_after | 38 |
| 23 | NBS1_after | 39 |

Comment: Sorry for the wait! Thank you very much for the answer, worked great. I do have one small additional question: I'm using 9 pairs of datasets, so the colour palette loops back to the beginning on the end of the plot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpdoq.png). Do you know a way to "extend" the paired palette, or specify my own colours?

Comment: You can use `palette='tab20'` for 10 pairs of colors.  (`Paired` only contains 12 colors). If needed, you can also provide the palette as a list of colors.